# NetSuite Restlet External API - CORS request did not succeed

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0

I'm trying to write an eternal API for our company, enabled integration with external systems. For example Woo Commerce sending orders to NetSuite.

I have a basic rest written that just returns

```
function doGet(requestParams) {
    return "got";
}
```

My test html page is written as such

```
<script>
  // Create a request variable and assign a new XMLHttpRequest object to it.
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET', 'https://debugger.netsuite.com/app/site/hosting/restlet.nl?script=XXX&deploy=XXX ', true);
request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
request.onload = function () {

  // Begin accessing JSON data here
  var data = JSON.parse(this.response);

  if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400) {
    console.log(data);
  } else {
    console.log('error');
  }
}

// Send request
request.send();
</script>
```

All I can get though is

Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://debugger.netsuite.com/app/site/hosting/restlet.nl?script=XXX&deploy=XXX. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed)

How can I get this API working

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do this directly. There is no native Netsuite integration that will let you set CORS headers.

You could proxy your calls through an AWS lambda service and that would be quite performant and pretty inexpensive